# Free right resolution?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

As I can not find a question it must be particularly obvious but I do not see ... When one talks about free resolution, it's always with left resolution. Why are we not dealing with free right resolution?

$$ 0\to M\to F_0\to F_1\to\ldots $$

Comment: That would be an injective resolution. Free implies projective, not injective.

Comment: While every module is a quotient of a free module, not every module embeds into a free module.

Comment: For example $R=\mathbb Z$ and $M=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.  What do you do for $F_0$?

Comment: @bounceback You mean "that would not be"?

Comment: @Macadam: No, what he means is that a "free left resolution" can be understood as dealing with a sequence of projective modules, each mapping to the prior one. So the dual concept (you do talk about projective resolutions as more general than free resolutions), with "right resolutions", would be with a sequence of *injective* modules, each mapping into the next one.